# Query about URl tracking in web pages

Tags: asp.net

How to track cuurent page url means that user either come from any search enjine like google or user directly type url in browser

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know how the user came to your site, you can use the referrer. But sometimes it is disabled on client side.

C# URL referrer (not tested):

```
string MyReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Comment: referrer is used to chk prevoius page url if user type direct link on browser and if user come from google than it should record that how many user come from google or how many user come directly from browser url

Comment: That is possible with the referrer. But when the user disabled the referrer or uses noreferrer service you will get as result that the user came directly.

Comment: can u give me example sample of code i am using asp.net with C#

Comment: this cant work beacuse if user come first time it will show exceptions

Comment: When you got an exception the user has directly accessed your page or disabled/removed referrer.

Comment: so how can i fixed this problem

Comment: You can use a Try/Catch construct to handle the exception.

Comment: is this help ful if user come after search enjinge will it record user count

Comment: The try/catch construct is only for the users with no referrer. For the other users you can do with the referrer whatever you want.